# What is the largest number of regions formed by $6$ planes in space?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, planar-graphs

What is the largest number of regions formed by $6$ planes in space?

---

I found this equation for the maximum number of regions $R_n$ created by $n$ lines:
$$\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$$

This seems to be very similar to the original question, but I don't know how to use it in a way that is helpful.

Comment: You have posted multiple question recently, none of which show even the slightest effort.  This is not a homework site.  Please edit your post to show what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @lulu  I figured out the first question and have included some more details.

Comment: How did you derive that formula?

Comment: @lulu  I found a reccurence.

Comment: Just as with with lines problem, you can look all of this up on line.  [This article](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/mwoltermann/Dorrie/67.pdf)  contains a readable argument for the $n$ planes in space problem.  But, really, you should try to work these problems on your own.

Comment: @lulu Thanks!  The article really helped me understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For the first problem, you can think about recursion.

$$f(n) = f(n-1) + n$$